# How to get my VBA Code to loop through all sheets in workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have 5 worksheets in my workbook(Table 1, Table 2, Table 3, Table 4 and Combined). The main Worksheet is the one I am trying to combine the other 4 into and place the data on the next blank line.

I have been googling different code solutions for weeks to no avail.

When I step through the macro and use the loop (do while, for and Each), it is only looping through Table 1 perfectly. But I cannot get it to loop through Sheets 2-4.

I think I know where my issue is, but in my weeks of googling, I still can't find the solution.  I think the issue is on the line where it reads "Sheets("Table 1").Select".  Because the code seems to work till it gets to that line. Then it "of course" goes back to Table 1.

This is a test group for a much larger project. I have to pull information from 500 documents that are all set up in the exact same position, but I have to get these 4 to work first.

'I have tried this:

```
Dim iSheet As Object

For Each iSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    MsgBox iSheet.Name
    Next iSheet
```

'And I tried this:

```
Dim useWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim totalWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim tableAsNumeric As Integer
Dim startingTable As Integer

'For Each Current In Worksheets
'Table Name = Table in Worksheets

startingTable = 1

Set totalWorkSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Table 1")

For Each useWorkSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    tableAsNumeric = Val(useWorkSheet.Name)

    'If tableAsNumeric >= startingTable Then

'Do While I >= Worksheet("Table 1")
'I = I + 1
```

'I have also tried a for loop and as many others as there are out on the net...  Nothing works...

This is the code I need help with:

```
Sub TFRdataExtract()
'
' TFRdataExtract Macro
' Extract Data from Individual TFR files to the combined file.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'

Dim iSheet As Object

For Each iSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    MsgBox iSheet.Name

    Sheets("Table 1").Select
    Range("AB1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-27], 7,100)"
    Range("AC1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-24], 14,100)"
    Range("AD1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-19],23,100)"
    Range("AE1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-10],22,100)"
    Range("AF1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[1]C[-31], 23,100)"
    Range("AG1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[1]C[-16], 10,100)"
    Range("AH1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[1]C[-13],13,100)"
    Range("AI1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[2]C[-34],22,100)"
    Range("AJ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[2]C[-25],18,100)"
    Range("AK1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[2]C[-16],21,100)"
    Range("AL1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[3]C[-37],21,100)"
    Range("AM1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[3]C[-28],17, 100)"
    Range("AN1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[3]C[-21],34,100)"
    Range("AO1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[4]C[-40],28,100)"
    Range("AP1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[4]C[-35], 7,100)"
    Range("AQ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[4]C[-34],10,100)"
    Range("AR1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[4]C[-29],10,100)"
    Range("AS1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[4]C[-21],22,100)"
    Range("AT1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[5]C[-45],26,100)"
    Range("AU1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[6]C[-46],18,100)"
    Range("AV1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[6]C[-37],55,100)"
    Range("AW1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[7]C[-48],36,100)"
    Range("AX1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[7]C[-39],30,100)"
    Range("AY1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[7]C[-28],12,100)"
    Range("AZ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[8]C[-51],20,100)"
    Range("BA1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[8]C[-35],12,100)"
    Range("BB1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[8]C[-31],20,100)"
    Range("BC1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[9]C[-54],25,100)"
    Range("BD1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[9]C[-45],15,100)"
    Range("BE1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[9]C[-39],23,100)"
    Range("BF1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[10]C[-57],17,100)"
    Range("BG1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[10]C[-56],17,100)"
    Range("BH1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[10]C[-52],13,100)"
    Range("BI1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[10]C[-42],14,100)"
    Range("BJ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[10]C[-38],15,100)"
    Range("BK1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[12]C[-62],11,100)"
    Range("BL1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[12]C[-62],12,100)"
    Range("BM1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[12]C[-59],10,100)"
    Range("BN1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[12]C[-57], 7,100)"
    Range("BO1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[12]C[-55],7,100)"
    Range("BP1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[12]C[-55],11,100)"
    Range("BQ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[12]C[-53],12,100)"
    Range("BR1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[12]C[-50],8,100)"
    Range("BS1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[12]C[-47],12,100)"
    Range("BT1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[13]C[-71],10,100)"
    Range("BU1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[13]C[-71],20,100)"
    Range("BV1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[13]C[-66],10,100)"
    Range("BW1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[13]C[-63],10,100)"
    Range("BX1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[13]C[-62],8,100)"
    Range("BY1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[13]C[-61],7,100)"
    Range("BZ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[13]C[-59],9,100)"
    Range("CA1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[13]C[-57],10,100)"
    Range("CB1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[13]C[-55],13,100)"
    Range("CC1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[14]C[-80],12,100)"
    Range("CD1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[14]C[-80],13,100)"
    Range("CE1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("CE1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[14]C[-77],15,100)"
    Range("CF1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[14]C[-72],7,100)"
    Range("CG1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[14]C[-71],13,100)"
    Range("CH1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[14]C[-67],14,100)"
    Range("CI1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[14]C[-62],7,100)"
    Range("CJ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[15]C[-87],13,100)"
    Range("CK1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[15]C[-85],15,100)"
    Range("CL1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[15]C[-82],11,100)"
    Range("CM1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "L16,11,100)"
    Range("CN1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[15]C[-73],15,100)"
    Range("CO1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[15]C[-68],8,100)"
    Range("CP1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[17]C[-93],19,100)"
    Range("CQ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[17]C[-80],22,100)"
    Range("CR1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[18]C[-95],27,100)"
    Range("CS1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[18]C[-82],18,100)"
    Range("CT1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[19]C[-97],45,100)"
    Range("CU1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[19]C[-89],22,100)"
    Range("CV1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[19]C[-81],49,100)"
    Range("CW1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[20]C[-91],21,100)"
    Range("CX1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[21]C[-101],16,100)"
    Range("CY1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(22,27,100)"
    Range("CZ1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
    Range("CY1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-50
    Range("AB1:CY1").Select
    Range("CY1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Combined").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Next iSheet

End Sub
```

I need to loop through all 4 Worksheets and paste data onto the Combined file into the next blank line.

Comment: Your first example should have worked fine.  Are you sure your code is in a Sub or Function?

Comment: Very good question, I didn't even think of that one! Will check it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
For sht = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Debug.Print sht
    'your code here
    Sheets(sht).Activate'or
    Sheets(Sheets(sht).Name).Activate
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub TFRdataExtract()

    Dim iSheet As Worksheet, rngCopy As Range

    For Each iSheet In ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets

        If iSheet.Name Like "Table*" Then

            With iSheet                                            '<< no need to activate!
                .Range("AB1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-27], 7,100)" '<< no need to select!
                .Range("AC1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-24], 14,100)"
                .Range("AD1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-19],23,100)"
                'etc etc


                Set rngCopy = .Range("AB1:CY1")
            End with

            'assign values directly
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined").Range("A2")
                .Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, _
                        rngCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rngCopy.Value
            End with

        End If 'EDIT - added

    Next iSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: I've done this one and it skips everything from "With iSheet" all the way to the second "End With".

Comment: It should only do that for sheets whose name didn't begin with "Table"

Comment: When I do the above code, it gives me a "Compile error: Next without For"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help. Commented to help understand what is going on.

```
'// Modify as desired, like to empty rows/columns.
Private Function GetRangeToCopy(zWorksheet As Worksheet) As Range
    Set GetRangeToCopy= zWorksheet.UsedRange
End Function


'// Modify to add spacing or whatnot.
Private Function GetDestinationRange(zDestinationWorksheet As Worksheet, zRowCount As Long, zColumnCount As Long) As Range
    Dim zReturnRange As Range
    Dim zNewRowIndex As Long

    Let zNewRowIndex = zDestinationWorksheet.UsedRange.End.Row + 3 '// Increase to add more rows between inserts.
    Set zReturnRange = zDestinationWorksheet.

    Set GetDestinationRange = zReturnRange
End Function


'// Copies a range to the destination range.
Private Sub CopyRange(zSourceRange As Range, zDestinationRange As Range)
    '// This is where copying styles and such would be done.
    '// We will just call copy for simplicity.

    '// Clear.
    Call zDestinationRange.Clear

    '// Copy.
    Call zSourceRange.Copy(zDestinationRange)
End Sub


'// Copy worksheets to a destination worksheet.
'// Destination worksheet can be a worksheet loaded into a different workbook altogether.
Public Sub CopyWorksheetsTo(zDestinationWorksheet As Worksheet, zClearDestinationWorksheet As Boolean = False _
zPopupCurrentWorksheet As Boolean = True)
    Dim zCurrentWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim zCurrentWorksheet_Var As Variant
    Dim zRangeToCopy As Range
    Dim zDestinationRange As Range

    '// Clear destination.
    If (zClearDestinationWorksheet) Then
        Call zDestinationWorksheet.UsedRange.Clear
    End If

    '// Cycle through each worksheet in the workbook.
    ForEach zCurrentWorksheet_Var in Worksheets
        '// this allow us the Intellisense while coding.
        Set zCurrentWorksheet = zCurrentWorksheet_Var

        '// Make sure this isn't the destination worksheet.
        If (zCurrentWorksheet.Name <> zDestinationWorksheet.Name) Then
            '// Popup worksheet name.
            If (zPopupCurrentWorksheet) Then
                Call MsgBox(zCurrentWorksheet.Name)
            End If

            '// Get range to be copied.
            Set zRangeToCopy = GetRangeToCopy(zCurrentWorksheet)

            '// Get destination range.
            Set zDestinationRange = GetDestinationRange(zDestinationWorksheet)

            '// Copy range.
            Call CopyRange(zRangeToCopy, zDestinationRange)
        End If
    Next xCurrentWorksheet_Var
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub procedure 'CopyRange' does not handle merged cells in destination.

Answer (score 0):

*To loop on all Worksheets*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
'   // Declare your Variables
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    '// loop on all sheets
    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        Debug.Print Sht.Name
        'Do something
    Next

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet. I am already using this in a macro.

```
Sub Combine()

' ensure you have placed the "combined" worksheet as the first sheet

'variable declaration
Dim J As Integer

'copying header row from second sheet
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combined").Range("A1")



'copying data from other sheets
For J = 2 To 4
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combined").Range("A65536")_
.End(xlUp) (2)
Next

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("combined").Columns.AutoFit


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should try to avoid **.Select**. Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook

        For Each ws In .Worksheets

            If ws.Name = "Table 1" Then

                With ws

                    .Range("AB1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-27], 7,100)"
                    .Range("AC1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-24], 14,100)"
                    .Range("AD1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-19],23,100)"
                    .Range("AE1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-10],22,100)"
                    .Range("AF1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[1]C[-31], 23,100)"
                    '....... Add more formulas
                    .Range("AB1:CY1").Copy


                End With

                With .Worksheets("Combined").Range("A2")
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                End With

            End If

        Next ws

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work but skips the macro from "With ws" all the way to "Next ws". It just will not enter the macro...